# How to upgrade crypto-utils on fedora 14 to fc21 version

Tags: linux, encryption, fedora

I'm using Fedora 14 to generate a self-signed certificate for our internal webserver serving our bugzilla bug tracking system.

Fedora 14 crypto-utils generates a SHA1 signature, which current version chrome rejects as being insecure (It works OK in IE).

This was updated in Fedora 21 crypto-utils (2.4.1-56) https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1062444

My current version is 2.4.1-27

```
# yum list crypto-utils
....
Installed Packages
crypto-utils.x86_64              2.4.1-27                @fedora
```

I don't want to upgrade the full system, but instead do want to get the newer version of crypto-utils installed.

I tried:

```
yum update crypto-utils
```

but this tells me "No Packages marked for update"

What are the steps I need to take to get the newer version of crypto-utils running on my machine?

EDIT: I followed NoAngel's guide below (thanks), but it looks like my version of Fedora is too old to allow an easy upgrade. I needed newer versions of three other packages to build the Fedora21 version of crypto-utils.

```
$ rpm -i tmp/crypto-utils-2.4.1-56.fc21.src.rpm
...
$ rpmbuild -ba crypto-utils.spec
error: Failed build dependencies:
    nss-devel >= 3.13.1 is needed by crypto-utils-2.4.1-56.fc14.x86_64
    nss-util-devel >= 3.13.1 is needed by crypto-utils-2.4.1-56.fc14.x86_64
    xmlto is needed by crypto-utils-2.4.1-56.fc14.x86_64
```

Instead I just used an online http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/ tool to generate what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You are using outdated unsupported old OS, which have many security problems, and You need upgrade or fix them by yourself.

If You still want to do it, thats how:

Download a source code for crypto-utils. Extract it. Then run from source extracted folder:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick Answer. I've never built from source before. It looks easy.  - Where do you find the correct source code tarball?

Comment: For example, here: http://ftp-srv2.kddilabs.jp/Linux/packages/fedora/releases/21/Everything/source/SRPMS/c/crypto-utils-2.4.1-56.fc21.src.rpm

Comment: how to build rpm from srpm: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM

Comment: Thanks Again - It looks like my distro is too old to upgrade easily. I used an on-line generator instead. Looks like time to upgrade to a newer Fedora.

Comment: Well, I tested it on my Centos 6 server for fun, worked and created rpm, even from Fedora 21 srpm. I needed to install some dependencies(which were wrote in error messages), then it worked. Probably Fedora 14 is too old, if it cannot build this.